# C++ throw exception when deleting invalid address

Tags: c++, exception

I'm making a custom allocator and I know when the application tries to deallocate an invalid address but I don't know what exception should I throw. For example:

```
...
int *a=new int;
delete a;
delete a;
...
```

When the second delete happens I know that I don't have that address allocated in my memory pool and I need to throw an exception for the user to know that at some point in the program he tried to deallocate an invalid address.

Comment: So you are implementing `operator new` and `operator delete` or are you talking about an actual [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator)? Can you please give a bit more context?

Comment: I'm implementing ```operator new``` and ```operator delete``` and I have at the start of the program a memory pool with memory available and memory allocated. When the ```operator delete``` is called I know if the address the user wants to delete is allocated or if it's an invalid address. And if it's an invalid address I would want to throw an exception to let the user know (same as the default allocator)

Comment: By the way you can use Valgrind to catch double delete errors like this.

Comment: When my function to deallocate memory is called I only know the address the user wants to deallocate. And by checking if the address is allocated I can see if that address is valid or invalid and I would like to throw an exception if that address is invalid same as the default allocator.

Comment: What kind of exception do you get with the default operators? An Acess Violation (windows) or SIGSEGV (linux)? Those are not C++ level exceptions, but OS level. Are you trying to cause something like that when a user of your `operator delete` passes an invalid pointer?

Comment: I'm getting Access violation reading location and yes I'm trying to cause something like that.

Comment: The correct course of action is not to throw an exception, but to `abort()`. Exceptions are a way for your program to handle issues external to your program, not for handling programming bugs. By definition, when a bug occurs, the program doesn't know what is going on, and there is now way it can correctly handle the error. You will just end up with exceptions after exceptions. At least with an `abort()` you have the possibility to get a core dump where the bug happened.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu - I suppose a question to ask is why you need to use new/delete directly? You possibly could use smart pointers to sort out the memory management for you (certainly in your example you could). In my code these days I don't allow the use of new/delete except within the `make_unique` or `make_shared` functions (or some very specific use case which is heavily scrutinised)... could be something to think about

Comment: oh wait... not sure if that works within operator new/delete... never tried that...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `operator delete` is allowed to throw any exception. Throwing an exception from an `operator delete` causes undefined behavior. See [[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#stc.dynamic.deallocation-3).

Even if you could diagnose double-deletes this way, using `delete a;` twice still causes undefined behavior. This is unavoidable, for example because `delete a;` also calls the destructor first and you are generally not allowed to call the destructor twice on an object.

And even that aside, calling `operator delete` twice on the same pointer without intervening allocation still causes undefined behavior, because the first `operator delete` call ends the storage duration of the allocated memory, making the pointer value *invalid*, and passing an invalid pointer value to *any* deallocation function causes undefined behavior, see [[basic.stc]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#stc-4).

The only thing you can do when a user tried to double delete a pointer is to abort the program, e.g. by a call to `std::abort`. This is probably the best course of action, since undefined behavior already happened and so continuing the program would be pointless or even a security risk.

Comment: I don't understand how the ```operator delete``` is not allowed to throw an exception. For my example code, if I run it on the default allocator on the second delete an exception is thrown. Also, I need to throw an exception when an application tries to delete an invalid address.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu No, there is no exception thrown when you double delete with the default `operator delete`. However double-delete causes undefined behavior anyway and so your platform probably is offering some debugging mechanism that is giving you the error message or you are seeing an access violation or something similar.

Comment: Yes, I see the access violation. Now if I use my custom allocator instead of the default one when the second delete is called my function gets called and if I don't throw an exception the main application will continue to run which is not right. In both situations custom/default allocator the behavior should be the same only the strategy to allocate memory should differ.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu There is no guarantee that you will get an access violation with the default `operator delete`. At most your particular platform is making that additional guarantee. Another compiler or platform may not. It is undefined behavior. If you want to know about your specific platform, you should add it to the question. And the access violation exception is *not* a C++ exception (although the name might suggest that).

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019. If I'm making a custom allocator in this situation when the user tries to deallocate an invalid address what should I do? What's the appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu I cannot help you regarding the windows-specific stuff. I would simply ignore the possibility (at least for a release build), because the user already failed if they try to double-delete. There is no recovery from that. The best you can do is give an error message for debug purposes and abort the program.

Comment: I understand that's what I'm going to do for the moment probably. Thanks for the information's and help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in exception for invalid address or invalid delete because exceptions are not supported natively for this errors.

You could make your own exception - its pretty simple - e.g.:

code below copied from [here](https://peterforgacs.github.io/2017/06/25/Custom-C-Exceptions-For-Beginners/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

struct MyException : public std::exception
{
    const char * what () const throw ()
    {
        return "C++ Exception";
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw MyException();
    }
    catch (MyException& e)
    {
        std::cout << "MyException caught" << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        // Other errors
    }
}
```

**Note:** see Walnut's comment about exception handling before using this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't know about this if I decide to use exceptions, creating a custom one seems the best approach.

Comment: The `throw()` dynamic exception specification has been deprecated since C++11 and will be removed in C++20. Please don't use it. Use `noexcept` instead. In order to avoid mistakes, you should also add the `override` qualifier to the `what` function.

Comment: @walnut thanks for that : ) didn't know it was getting removed in 20. I personally don't use exception handling since a long time, but the question was asking which exception to use - also the code is not mine - its copied from the link (as I noted at the top) so I won't change it, but I'll add a note there to see your comment : )